# 流水の動画から水の中を流れる物体の数をカウントする方法について

Tags: python, opencv

流れる水の動画から水の中を流れる物体の総数をカウントしたいのですが、どのような方法が考えられますでしょうか？

条件
・動画は定点撮り
・流れる方向は一定
・流れてくる物体は大きさの違いはありますが基本的に1種類。ただしゴミのようなものが流れてくる可能性あり。

オプティカルフローを使えばなんとかなる？なども考えたのですが、基本方針が決まりません。
どのような方法がいいか、参考になるサイトなどご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: 逆にゴミ関連ですが、この辺に何かヒントがあるかも。[河川漂流ゴミ輸送量の自動連続モニタリング手法の開発と最上川観測への適用](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jscejhe/71/4/71_205/_pdf), [サーモカメラを用いた河川漂流ゴミ判別精度の検討](http://library.jsce.or.jp/jsce/open/00035/2016/71-02/71-02-0033.pdf), [河川漂流ゴミ輸送量に関する自動モニタリング技術の検討](https://www.rs.noda.tus.ac.jp/hydrolab/papers/2013/2013003.pdf)

Comment: なるほど！こういう検索はしていなかったです！参考にさせていただきます！